# API to get reviews from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to fetch some reviews of the applications published on Google Play Store, but not the application that I developed? For example, what if I want to get the reviews of big name application like Whatsapp or Twitter? Or is it only available for the developer of the said application? I am reading [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews) but I am not really clear enough on the subject.

And if it's not possible to get such reviews, what alternative can I do?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the reviews of the apps through API that you do not own.

From the doc:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started

> To start making API calls, you’ll set up and manage the Google Play
>   Developer API directly from the Google Play Console. The API can only
>   be managed by the owner of your Google Play Developer account

Comment: Thanks, that means I can't possibly get any reviews on apps like Facebook or Chrome through the API. Do you have any alternative you can suggest? Like has there been any dataset available regarding reviews or do you know other review sites which have open API?

Comment: You need an access token to access the APIs which can be setup only using the owner's Google play console. I haven't seen any way to get the reviews without the help of the app owner.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. If you're like me, in need of some alternative to reviews dataset (which apparently Google Play Store doesn't give you access to in their API), I have found a good resource. [Amazon review dataaset](http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/)

Answer (score -1):

I just put a repo on github for pulling reviews from the play store; I've read this question appear here many times and decided to publish my code; hopefully it'll help.

Demo: https://www.reviewsmaker.com/api/demo/playstore/

On git: https://github.com/ilanpatao/google-playstore-reviews-api

Basically by using the appid I was able to extract all the reviews for any listed applications, the output is a linted JSON return with review dates, author names, author images, rating and review body;

Here's a sample of the return from Clash of Clans app:

```
{
   "reviews":[
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:49:06",
         "author":"Alan Ross",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mAqFuPsDx2X3WI0L4iSOalyJ_ypyIKDNGTph8R-",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"great game but update process slow plz update 1 week gap required"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:48:54",
         "author":"Ajib Putra",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mDjbpSwUB8YXjbFt4EkAcLDbdoRvQxRMT9LkOFt2w",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"very cool"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:48:07",
         "author":"Mukta Varshney",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-nKMrqfWnQq4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AKxrwcbG1L4uysKWcRe52V-Li7wwA-EG1w/mo/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"it is an Amazing game."
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:47:59",
         "author":"Unni P Unnip",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-feiC0Hr2pLc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AKxrwcZ1_Yzwlzz6H_5W9O8YbJuS0NV63w/mo/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"best game than pubg"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:47:33",
         "author":"CAPITAL N",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mDXaRMjE4Cwa_MwSTh_RbPJfz6Y3jR7Onjve50Y",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"Best android game built."
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:46:59",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mCA_VCuGW8CjDdsPBJn_CYqmHHCVkQ5BoUckbfGJA",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"Wants town hall 12 soon"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:46:52",
         "author":"technical king",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mDEsrhmf22Rmo1IraiheAwxOtwoLDVkIsW3LpklCA",
         "rating":1,
         "reviewText":"Very good"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:46:18",
         "author":"Aliul Hasan",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mCj8hyc4K7BFgS-rG0it0MgCdf2blIUZz9aEhDp",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"It is my favourite game"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:46:06",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-A1QJpTM-HUE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/fCaAjnjRgtU/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"Very good"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:46:02",
         "author":"Uma Mahesh N",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mDseFeqj6p-Lq2o9eBY-xHRabbzJKbFHDBjDR7c",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"Nice game"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:45:56",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mB7UUy8rHeMP2aij8xALDYCnMz5Eptj6zMKx4tc",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"cool game"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:45:20",
         "author":"sasha chrito",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mDQ_wDRSD9LTRJ2uQ1xrxMtJ-VbLmH1ldXAIr_-",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"I LOVE COC very much"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:45:11",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mC1BQ9jV9oDZ0uk_JqRlSVwREzBYeB2nxBzEZUk",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"Love you"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:45:05",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-M1B7jHyF_7k/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ofQloqYK0ow/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"cool"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:44:52",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-veyUNcyyVxk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/jjtX-sel30Y/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"i am bangladesi. i love coc because it give me pleasure and strategy knowledge i play coc always and i wish i become a very big player so thank you coc and help me become a big player"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:44:47",
         "author":"Axolotl",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mDJHtsL-q-qh2MBp8q5l3O4jbyAzPySG1ixgRYp",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"Nå er det et sinnsykt bra spill spessielt på grunn av klan krig!"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:44:40",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-D70Uc0EaR7g/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/nVQ0KIFDN88/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"amazing"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:44:10",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-XSWF9xLB6GE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/lEIvOz40AF4/photo.jpg",
         "rating":4,
         "reviewText":"что за фиг ня что за обнова у меня когда нажимаю на новости игра вылетает сообщения пол кортинки не видно я не доволен"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:43:58",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Mzn6BQsVE8Y/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4HZVmyK7YXs/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"gajab"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:43:13",
         "author":"Bryan Simon Sanchez Eranista",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mC-Zpn3Ao8qza49REV0j4EeEmkoeH8z5Z3vLg9c",
         "rating":1,
         "reviewText":"do you know that your supercell i.d . has been a usefull way to the scammer to get account . my 2 account has been connected to SC ID without my permission. its your work right . so your the one who can help me bring back my account ?"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:43:11",
         "author":"Vivek Palina",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-940QFsCKBZk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AKxrwcYouGAXRzeaGnK-FtojN5h9RclgIQ/mo/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"one of the world's best game"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:43:09",
         "author":"Parag Jadhav",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mAjd9hbKxPDapG_iNDMhp--rDxSRn4EuR2hxMkkyA",
         "rating":2,
         "reviewText":"Sometimes when my clanmate donates troops to me,they goes nowhere...He can see that donation is successful but I never receives them ;("
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:42:36",
         "author":"꧁Chun Yuen꧂",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mABOsBzSbRx9aPaCSEuEHqldojJOlv7k9uVGrq7",
         "rating":1,
         "reviewText":"i cant login my id VIP_小俊"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:41:55",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-c3qzpJqou54/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/PKhJRWfg1FE/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"As"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:41:50",
         "author":"Suman kumari Kumari",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-2Mj1RHoHuYc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AKxrwcaB3vrxki8zZatOD0sf3s57pVDURw/mo/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"a mamu bole teo akbham jaksh"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:40:46",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-M5qa-sgHFm4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/CBJ70thT3kw/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"best game i ever played"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:40:37",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Zy_RY879NjI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/oe-FOPjbETI/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"Good"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:40:35",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-yM1irpRIfIM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/oI337F1EobE/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"it's amazing how much you love it and I love it"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:40:27",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-iKB3-FtuBj8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/fEA1xElg15Y/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"Very nice game"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:40:17",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-TqROmpFxuL4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/-wcpyMawShg/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"Super"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:39:45",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-dCe6IL4sET4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/vcyWyVuPg8c/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"nice gam e"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:37:48",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-dUsYZNOCM6w/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ixVSqeMPQRI/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"this game is amazing"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:37:47",
         "author":"ENTER TAINER",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mAVZSf9oCQWSI0_eSoaIEpimAjujb93F8rptlAO",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"nice phone I have ever played"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:37:39",
         "author":"MANI KANTA",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-vxI-1-gBgEM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AKxrwcYjoBKCjZBtYSHUGZwKX2vPhWP_MQ/mo/photo.jpg",
         "rating":4,
         "reviewText":"IAM IOST MORE TROPHY SUPER CELL SEE MYYY BASE ONE TIME #PR28U0PUV"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:37:18",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-evaTlieF-v0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/l3Y9BFuCF4I/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"fantastic it nice what i say waoooo "
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:36:39",
         "author":"Jefferson Corro",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-l-1AG0dRhxQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AKxrwcZo_NHiv3QUizUsD0WA6hWY2dEZtA/mo/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"thank you"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:36:30",
         "author":"Anita Gurung",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7FkYFO0EuUQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AKxrwcZKGPM4SyVdrZ3hnDr_FI8t80m9Rw/mo/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"Fine"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:36:19",
         "author":"A Google user",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mD1jdEM917g92sMPMWBkHe6Qf5HC9ya64vj8yUb",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"THIS IS MY 3 FAVOURITE GAME ON PLAYSTORE I LOVE COC PLAYING ALL THE TIME"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:35:57",
         "author":"anil rai",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-FO3att02aNE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AKxrwcYJeh-JWq8d6OhXLTFhHbQWAGzjUw/mo/photo.jpg",
         "rating":3,
         "reviewText":"excellent"
      },
      {
         "date":"2018-12-24 13:35:50",
         "author":"prem saxena",
         "authorPhoto":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-l0wQKnuCD5I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AKxrwcZKymagN4ljshyOQghWp3EzUNZMQw/mo/photo.jpg",
         "rating":5,
         "reviewText":"so cool i will come after 3 years"
      }
   ],
   "appid":"com.supercell.clashofclans",
   "displayingLatest":"40 reviews",
   "author":"Ilan Patao - ilan@reviewsmaker.com"
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Code where is things like "// Call my API" that call not working API is not very useful.